# Python parsing a huge file

Tags: python, file, parsing

I am looking for efficient way to load a huge file with data.

The file has the following format

`1\tword1\tdata`

`2\tword2\tdata`

`3\tword3\tdata`

`\r\n`

`1\tword4\tdata`

`2\tword2\tdata`

`\r\n`

where `\r\n` defines the end of the sentences which consist of the words.

I am interested in loading the file and in saving the structure, i.e. I want to refer to sentence and to the word in the sentence, in general as result I want to get something like this

```
data = [sentence1, sentence2,... ]
```

where `sentence = [word1,word2,...]`

Loading file line by line take a lot of time, loading file by batches much more efficient, however I don't know how to parse and divide the data to the sentences.

Currently I use the following code

```
def loadf(filename):
    n = 100000
    data = []
    with open(filename) as f:
        while True:
            next_n_lines = list(islice(f, n))
            if not next_n_lines:
                break
            data.extend([line.strip().split('\t') for line in next_n_lines])
```

With this code I don't know how to divide the data to the sentences, in addition I suspect that `extend` not actually extend the current list but create a new one and reassign, because it's extremely slow.

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: "Loading file line by line take a lot of time, loading file by batches much more efficient" - you sure about that? Did you actually time it? Python reads the file in chunks to feed the line iterator, so you don't have to handle that yourself.

Comment: What is the file size approximately?

Comment: @TimZimmermann, ~700Mb

Comment: @user2357112, let me rephrase it, running `extend` on batch of lines was faster that `append` each line every time.

Comment: @user16168: That probably depends on exactly how your `append`-based code was structured.

Comment: You may try to use `for line in sys.stdin`. I recently used it to deal with a 1000MB-sized file and it took just a few seconds to read it (on an SSD). On Linux/Mac OS you would use `python PYTHONFILE.py < DATAFILE`. However, I'm not sure whether it's the fastest way of doing it.

Comment: @TimZimmermann: You'd probably use input redirection with `<` rather than `cat`.

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14289421/how-to-use-mmap-in-python-when-the-whole-file-is-too-big

Comment: related: [How to read tokens without reading whole line or file](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20019503/4279)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about:

```
import csv
from itertools import groupby

with open(yourfile) as fin:
    tabin = csv.reader(fin, delimiter='\t')
    sentences = [[el[1] for el in g] for k, g in groupby(tabin, bool) if k]
```

Comment: It's amazing, it takes just few seconds, thank you very much!